# How to satisfy a+b = 10?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, parametrization

Consider the line parametrized by
\begin{align*} 
x&= 4t + 2,\\ 
y& = t+2.
\end{align*}Find vector $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ that's parallel to this line and satisfies $a+b = 10$.

I know that "a" is 4t+2 and "b" is t+2 but idk how to make it satisfy the equation a + b = 10.

Comment: You mean $(a,b)$ is a multiple of $(4,1)$?

Comment: What do you know about vectors that are parallel to a given line?

Comment: I got t=6/5 after solving (4t+2)+(t+2)=10.

Comment: You’re supposed to find a vector _parallel_ to the line, not _on_ it.

Answer (score 5):

$$(x,y)=(4t+2,t+2)=(4,1)t+(2,2)$$
That means vector $(a,b)$ is a multiple of $(4,1)$, since $(2,2)$ is just an offset. Then $$a=4k\\b=k\\a+b=10$$
Solve ang get $k=2$ and $$(a,b)=(8,2)$$